# How to connect from SqlKata to postgras database?

Tags: sqlkata

I am working with dot net core in visual studio and connected to postgras sql by using Npgsql and now i want to query the database by using sqlkata but i can't connect to my postgras data base, can anyone help me? I install it and follow the instruction base on this link [enter link description here](https://sqlkata.com/docs/#getting-started) but it doesn't connect and throw exception"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server..."

Comment: This exception means you have a wrong connection string, make sure the user, password, port and db name are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create custom PostgresCompiler

```
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=localhost;Username=username;Password=pass;Database=db name");
            connection.Open();
            var compiler2 = new MyPostgresCompiler();
            var db2 = new QueryFactory(connection, compiler2);
            var list = new XQuery(connection, compiler2).From("employee").Get();
```

and MyPostgresCompiler is:

```
`public class MyPostgresCompiler : PostgresCompiler{
public MyPostgresCompiler()
{
    OpeningIdentifier = string.Empty;
    ClosingIdentifier = string.Empty;
}
public override string WrapValue(string value)
{
    return value;
}}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
using SqlKata;
using SqlKata.Compilers;
using SqlKata.Execution;
using Npgsql; 

// Setup the connection and compiler
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(Host=localhost;Username=yourUserName;Password=yourPassword;Database=postgres";);
var compiler = new PostgresCompiler();

var db = new QueryFactory(connection, compiler);

// You can register the QueryFactory in the IoC container

var user = db.Query("Users").Where("Id", 1).Where("Status", "Active").First();
```